# Numpy - list of lists to flat array

Tags: python, numpy

I am in the processing phase of my machine learning algorithm where I need to see if a cat is going outside or not.
Currently my images are presented by multiple lists like below.
(this is how 1 image is shown, an array containing an array that represents 1 row of pixels in the image)

```html
[[125  71 116 ... 255 255 255]
 [102 128 137 ... 255 255 255]
 [101  96  82 ... 255 255 255]
 ...
 [148 151 149 ...  55  51  49]
 [150 149 147 ...  52  50  49]
 [143 143 147 ...  50  50  50]]
```

But I want them in this format (Where the inner lists are gone, but you still can show the image):

```html
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   3.,  18.,
        18.,  18., 126., 136., 175.,  26., 166., 255., 247., 127.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
        30.,  36.,  94., 154., 170., 253., 253., 253., 253., 253., 225.,
       172., 253., 242., 195.,  64.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  49., 238., 253., 253., 253., 253.,
       253., 253., 253., 253., 251.,  93.,  82.,  82.,  56.,  39.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
        18., 219., 253., 253., 253., 253., 253., 198., 182., 247., 241.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  80., 156., 107., 253.,
       253., 205.,  11.,   0.,  43., 154.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
...
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.])
```

These are the numbers of another picture, so the numbers does not matter, but the format does. Is there a way to get my format of 2 lists in a format like above.

Currently my fit refuses to work because of this.

This is how I get my images into the lists at the moment.

```js
X = []
y = []
def make_arrays():

  inside = os.path.join("input", "classificatie", "aanwezig")
  outside = os.path.join("input", "classificatie", "buiten")
  nothing = os.path.join("input", "classificatie", "niets")

  images = glob.glob(f"{inside}/*")

  for i in images:
      img = cv2.imread(i)
      x = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      X.append(x)
      y.append("inside")

  images = glob.glob(f"{outside}/*")

  for i in images:
      img = cv2.imread(i)
      x = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      X.append(x)
      y.append("outside")

  images = glob.glob(f"{nothing}/*")

  for i in images:
      img = cv2.imread(i)
      x = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      X.append(x)
      y.append("nothing")
  
  

make_arrays()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.array(x).ravel()
```

where `x` is the nested list.

Comment: Now my shape is broken of the image, I cannot show my image anymore

Comment: That's because you've changed the representation. You can use numpy's reshape method (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to return to the original shape, then your image can be rendered. Also: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. For further clarification, see: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes, I know. I do this always, also in my previous asked questions. This is a hard problem to type it out. I did my best and added my code that I use at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flatten()`

```
arr = np.array(arr).flatten().tolist()
```

Comment: I ment they are lists, not arrays. Excuse me

Comment: Check the answer now :)

Comment: This does not do the job. I have changed the description to make it more clear what I mean, but it is hard to type what is wrong. I tried my best.